# How to call reusable code in rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have a repeated methods in my model and I want to put those codes into one place and just want to access it into my model.

My model have few methods such as:

```
class ProductionProductivity7 < ApplicationRecord
def self.import1(file)
  spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
        header = spreadsheet.row(1)
        (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
          row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
          puts row.to_hash
          product = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new
          product.attributes = row.to_hash
          product.save!
    end
end
def self.search(search,compare)
  if search == "All"
    all.order(:id)
  elsif compare == "Bihar vs District"
    where("Districts = ? OR Districts = ?", search, "Bihar")
  else
    where(Districts: search)
  end
end
```

end

There are 3 more methods like this , I want to put this code block into helper and just want to call it inside model. For that I have tried this put these codes into my helper. And I am calling it using:

```
include ApplicationController.ProductionProductivity7sHelper
```

I am including this inside my model but I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `ProductionProductivity7sHelper' for ApplicationController:Class
```

My controller code is like this:

```
 def test
      @ProductionProductivity7s = ProductionProductivity7.search(params[:search],compare)
      a = ProductionProductivity7.query(@ProductionProductivity7s,params[:year],rain_fall_type,views,compare)
 end
```

I have added a module name code.rb in app folder.

```
   module Code
    def search(search_scope,compare)
        if search_scope == "All"
        all.order(:id)
        elsif compare == "Bihar vs District"
        where("Districts = ? OR Districts = ?", search_scope, "Bihar")
        else
        where(Districts: search_scope)
        end
    end
end
```

I just want to write all of my methods of my model somewhere it can be either module or helper without changing anything. Is it possible  I just want this code block in my model.

I am adding whole controller code and model code in gist files. Please have a look. [My controller and Model code link](https://gist.github.com/nwoow/fe3223d19395de7ec88dcb64db4116ee)

I am getting this error:

```
 undefined method `search' for #<Class:0x00007ff115974fd8> Did you mean? search1
```

Comment: How about using services instead?

Comment: Any example you can suggest

Comment: That must be your old code, yes? I don't see `extend Code` in your model. (`Code` seems like a bad name, but I assume you'll change that later?)

Comment: Updated whole previous and new code on gist

Comment: you can just write those methods on your `app/models/application_record.rb` and call it from any model like any model instance methods .. plus you'll have access to `self` as any of your calling model's instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just making a module like:

```
module Import1

  def import1(file)
    spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      puts row.to_hash
      product = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new
      product.attributes = row.to_hash
      product.save!
    end
  end

  def search(search_scope,compare)
    if search_scope == "All"
      all.order(:id)
    elsif compare == "Bihar vs District"
      where("Districts = ? OR Districts = ?", search_scope, "Bihar")
    else
      where(Districts: search_scope)
    end
  end

end
```

I think I would put it somewhere in your `app` folder so that you don't have problems with autoloading. You *could* put it in your root `app` folder, but that seems messy to me. You *could also* put it in your `models` folder, but then you have two very different kinds of things in the same folder which also seems messy to me. I think I would be tempted to create a new folder, something like `app/model_modules` or perhaps `app/shared_model_modules` and put your `import_1.rb` file in there. Then, it's clear what the file is.

And then do:

```
class ProductionProductivity7 < ApplicationRecord
  extend Import1
end
```

Or, how about using a service instead of a helper? IMO, it makes it more explicit what is going on whereas helpers can obsfucate where code lives.

A bare bones `BaseService` might look like:

```
class BaseService

  attr_accessor :args

  class << self

    def call(args=nil)
      new(args).call
    end

  end # Class Methods

  #=======================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #=======================================================================

    def initialize(args)
      @args = args || {}
      assign_args
    end

  private

    def assign_args
      args.each do |k,v|
        class_eval do 
          attr_accessor k
        end
        send("#{k}=",v)
      end
    end

end
```

Then, your file import service might look something like:

```
class ImportFileService < BaseService

  def call
    spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      puts row.to_hash
      product = klass.find_or_initialize_by(id: row["id"])
      product.attributes = row.to_hash
      product.save!
    end
  end

end
```

And you would call your service something like:

```
ImportFileService.call(file: file, klass: ProductionProductivity7)
```

Comment: I just want a simple answer I am updating my question

Comment: It's not that complicated. But, I appreciate what you are saying. Best of luck!

Comment: I added a file call Code.rb inside app folder and I am adding all of my model's action into it and extending in model. But getting error error undefined method `search' for #<Class:0x00007fd13e072288> I removed self I am using search inside controller.

Comment: The use of `search` as both a method name and an argument name *might* be causing problems (I'm speculating and haven't thought it through). You might try changing the argument to `search_scope`, as above. Also, you probably want to following naming conventions to match your file and module names. If the module is called `FooBar`, then the file should be called `foo_bar.rb`.

Comment: I changed my search to search_scope getting same error

Comment: It might help if you edit your question to show your current module code, your controller code where you are calling `search`, and your error stack. Otherwise, it's a little difficult to debug what might be happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174517/discussion-between-nilay-singh-and-jvillian).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, can you just create a module like so:

```
module ProductionProductivity7sHelper
  def import1(file) # notice I dropped 'self.'

    ...

  end

  ...

end
```

Then in your class, add:

```
class ProductionProductivity7 < ApplicationRecord
  extend ProductionProductivity7sHelper

  ...

end
```

This will add all the methods defined in the module as class methods for ProductionProductivity7. Note: This assumes that the methods you omitted are also class methods, i.e., begin with 'self.'

Comment: I created a module in lib folder called code but getting error.

Comment: I would just put production_productivity7s_helper.rb in the same folder as your other models.

Comment: It seems the OP wants to use the module in models other than ProductionProductivity7. I named the module as the method name in the first option of my answer (which is the same as yours sans naming).

Comment: I put my helper in my model folder and removed self from action but I am getting error undefined method `search' for #<Class:0x00007fd13e072288> Can you help me with this by updating answer

Comment: Hmmm. Can you fire up rails console and see if it recognizes ProductionProductivity7.search(search, compare) ?